# Update values of column so that it forms unique constraint with other column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have table A with columns a1,a2,a3 and table B with columns b1,b2. Currenly a2 column (Table A) contains all null values, I want to update a2 values by random values from b2 (table B). but when updating a2, I need to check it forms a unique with column a1. Means it should be (a1,a2) should be unique. what is the best way achieve this. I am using sql 2008. But i need to make sure it works oracle too.

I have tried following to select the random it happens fine.

`update A 
set a2 = (SELECT TOP 1 b2 FROM B ORDER BY newid()) 

where a2 is null 
 [but also need to form unique (a1,a2)]`

Comment: What should happen if it found composite key already. Means no other value is left to make this pair (a1,a2) unique ?

Comment: Yes. it is. no other value is left to make this pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I changed this answer after clarification that table `b` will have less rows than table `a`.*

This can be done with a `MERGE`.

First, assume table `a` has rows with the following `a1` values: `1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15, 15`.

Next, assume table `b` has rows with the following `b2` values: `102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108`.

Each `a1` value can be paired with the `b2` values on a rotating basis with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT a1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1 ORDER BY NULL) AS RowA
    FROM a) TableA
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT b2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by b2) AS RowB
    FROM b) TableB
ON Tablea.RowA = TableB.RowB

 A1 ROWA  B2 ROWB
--- ---- --- ----
  1    1 102    1 <-- first a1=1 goes with b2=102
  1    2 103    2 <-- second a1=1 goes with b2=103
  1    3 104    3 <-- third a1=1 goes with b2=104
  1    4 105    4 <-- fourth a1=1 goes with b2=105
  2    1 102    1 <-- start again: first a1=2 goes with b2=102
  2    2 103    2 <-- and so on...
  2    3 104    3
  2    4 105    4
  7    1 102    1
  7    2 103    2
 10    1 102    1
 10    2 103    2
 10    3 104    3
 10    4 105    4
 12    1 102    1
 12    2 103    2
 13    1 102    1
 13    2 103    2
 13    3 104    3
 13    4 105    4
 15    1 102    1
 15    2 103    2
```

This isn't enough for the merge because it doesn't identify table `a` rows uniquely, but `ROWID` can take care of that. Here's the full query:

```
MERGE INTO a
USING (
  SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT
        a.ROWID as ID,
        a1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1 ORDER BY a2) AS RowA
      FROM a) TableA
  INNER JOIN
   (SELECT b2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by b2) AS RowB
      FROM b) TableB
  ON Tablea.RowA = TableB.RowB) AtoB
ON (a.ROWID = AtoB.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.a2 = AtoB.b2
```

Here's what table `a` looks like after the update:

```
SELECT a1, a2 FROM a ORDER BY a1, a2;

 A1   A2
--- ----
  1  102
  1  103
  1  104
  1  105
  2  102
  2  103
  2  104
  2  105
  7  102
  7  103
 10  102
 10  103
 10  104
 10  105
 12  102
 12  103
 13  102
 13  103
 13  104
 13  105
 15  102
 15  103
```

Comment: Thanks gibbs for the answer, but the issue is Table B has few rows. it  wont never match the number of rows to Table A. Table B is mostly have less than 10 rows. it is table to store some type values

Comment: @kbird does `a.a2` have to have values from `b.b2`? If it just needs to be any value that will make `(a1, a2)` unique then this can be solved fairly easily.

Comment: yeah. it a.a2 is to have values from b.b2 ( it can be any but to make Unique(a1,a2)

Comment: OK, it's updated. This is an interesting problem - I hope the new solution works for you.

Comment: That's great news @kbird! Like I said, this was an interesting problem so I'm pleased the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query like this

```
    CREATE TABLE A(a1 INT ,a2 INT, a3 int)

    CREATE TABLE B(b1 INT ,b2 INT )

    INSERT A VALUES (2,NULL,1)
    INSERT A VALUES (3,NULL,1)
    INSERT A VALUES (4,NULL,1)
    INSERT A VALUES (5,NULL,1)
    INSERT A VALUES (2,NULL,1)

    INSERT B VALUES (2,7)
    INSERT B VALUES (12,7)
    INSERT B VALUES (2,7)
    INSERT B VALUES (2,7)
    INSERT B VALUES (2,17)
    INSERT B VALUES (2,70)

    INSERT B VALUES (22,1)

    SELECT * FROM A

    UPDATE A SET a2=(SELECT TOP 1 b2 FROM B WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM A T2 WHERE A.a1=T2.a1 AND A.a2=B.B2 )
    ORDER BY NEWID())

    SELECT * FROM A

    SELECT * FROM B

    DROP TABLE A

    DROP TABLE B
```

It would be better if you provide create and insert statement to diagnose the problem quickly.

Comment: This is just alias of A in inner query to validate if the pair doesn't  exists